# Passing $_POST to Db Class Without any Processing

Tags: php

I am trying to pass the `$_POST` global variable directly to the database through `mysqli_real_escape_string` without any processing...

Here is my code which is working fine.

1. What are the possible problem arising due to this type of coding?
2. What are the security risks?
3. Is it a good shortcut or there are still more...???

```
class Db{
...
More
...

    public function insert($args=array()){
        if(!isset($args['table']) || !isset($args['values'])){
            return false;
        }
        $table=$args['table'];
        $values=$this->process_insert($args['values']);
        $query="INSERT INTO {$table} {$values}";
        $result=$this->query2db($query); //method returns mysqli_query()
        if($result){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected function process_insert($data=array()){
        $values="";
        $fields="";
        $glue=", ";
        if(isset($data)){
            foreach($data as $key=> $value){
                $key=$this->escape($key);
                $value=$this->escape($value); //method returns mysqli_real_escape_string
                $fields .="{$key}".$glue;
                $values .="'{$value}'".$glue;
            }
            $fields=rtrim($fields, $glue);
            $values=rtrim($values, $glue);
            return "({$fields}) VALUES ({$values})";
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

...
More
...
}

if(!empty($_POST)){

    $query=array(
    'table'=>'users',
    'values'=> $_POST //<=== WHAT COULD BE THE PROBLEM HERE
    );

    $dbObj=new Db;
    $dbObj->insert($query);

}
```

**UPDATE-**

- I can use this for interactions with Android...
- Auto generate form having values in array format
- and validating using the array

Comment: no God no please no! Use `prepared statements` instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a request for a http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Ergec that can be used inside Db.php. And thanks. I will implement it in Db.php. Just wanted to know if it will cause any problem.

Comment: @deceze I want to know the risks or improvements as I want to use auto generate form fields and their validation.

Comment: @deceze thank you for formatting it :)

Comment: Front end JavaScript Validation and Back end PHP Filter_var or DB (Prepared/real_escape) will be there...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mysql_real_escape_string, i suggest using prepared statements. I always say, Never trust users input. Your data will be escaped but still gets in your database and do not forget the performance boost you get from using Prepared Statements!

Read this post [mysql_real_escape_string VS Prepared Statements](https://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html)

Comment: mysqli and prepared... Okay. I will implement it in the Db.php. Will there be any risk after implementing `prepared statment`.

Comment: Prepared statements are not necessary, and simply a performance boost for queries you're running repeatedly so the sql server doesn't have to parse and optimise them from scratch each time.

What IS important is that you're using bound or named parameters, which is quite different from prepared statements.

Comment: And also .. try using PDO over Mysqli

Comment: Did some research and found this answer why PDO "Ultimately, PDO wins this battle with ease. With support for twelve different database drivers (eighteen different databases!) and named parameters, we can ignore the small performance loss, and get used to its API. From a security standpoint, both of them are safe as long as the developer uses them the way they are supposed to be used (read: prepared statements)."

Comment: I just want to know the cosequences of using $_POST. The afterward processing is not a problem. Actually directly passing $_POST for further processing will save me from `if this is okay then attempt to write to db` blah blah...

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu, The main reason I suggest using PDO is that it is easier / more consistent for the standard use cases. the 'bindParam' stuff for mysqli is quite 'awkward'. Especially when using dynamically. PDO provides a easy to use standard. Same for fetching results.for mysqli, If the `mysqlnd` driver is not provided then it is a pain. With PDO then it is always the same and easy to use. imo, always use PDO unless some special facility of the database / driver is required.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks buddy. I am aware of PDO... I just wanted to know if I should take any action prior to `interact with database through mysqli or PDO or any such medium`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$key=$this->escape($key);
```

A clear vulnerability is here. `mysqli_real_escape_string` escapes for ***SQL string syntax***. Field names aren't using string syntax. Simple sample of what string escaping means:

```
$value = "Craig O'Connor";
$query = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES ('$value')";
                                  ^^^^^^^^
                              'Craig O'Connor'  ->  syntax error
```

With escaping:

```
$value = "Craig O'Connor";
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $value);
$query = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES ('$value')";
                                  ^^^^^^^^
                              'Craig O\'Connor'
```

The string escaping mechanism escaped the `'`. The assumption, the *prerequisite*, for `mysqli_real_escape_string` to do anything useful is that you're going to use the result **in an SQL string literal**. With field names you're not doing that. String escaping therefore doesn't do anything there. And therefore you're plainly vulnerable to SQL injection.

You *must* whitelist the allowable fields and filter them based on that whitelist. You *cannot* blindly accept any and all field names and simply use them as is. Not merely because it's somewhere between hard and impossible to *escape* field names, but also because the use of non-existing field names will result in a query error. You don't want query errors due to incorrect queries cobbled together from user input.

That is to say nothing about not using prepared statements in the first place, or that you're giving a user more or less free reign within your database…

Comment: I think prepared statement will reduce the possible risks. :)

Comment: Prepared statements still won't do anything for your field names.

Comment: Prepared Statements + Validation/Sanitisation using `filter_var` will overcome the possible risks?

Comment: Again: *whitelist your field names*. That's the only sane solution. You can even get that list from your database itself (MySQL's information schema). There is no sane sanitisation you can do on field names. But really, it's questionably why you have to dynamically generate your queries in the first place.

Comment: Okay I will implement the whitelisting too. I will achieve this-> `1.` List  fields as array `2.` Create/Update tables using those fields and this will help me be consistent unless I do not break it myself.